# Inductive hypothesis vs induction hypothesis

Tags: terminology, proof-writing, induction

I'm doing a proof by induction. Should I refer to **induction hypothesis** or to **inductive hypothesis** in the proof?

Comment: As far as I know, the basic case ($n = 0 or 1$) is the "base step", and assuming it's true for $n=k$ is the induction step.

Comment: I've definitely seen "induction step" and "inductive hypothesis" a lot. I don't remember seeing "induction hypothesis" much, but it gives almost as many Google results as "inductive hypothesis", so it seems all of them are fine.

Comment: rank, as long as the teacher\instructor\checker understands you, it's fine :)

Comment: @rank So am I. I guess its because "inductive hypothesis" is slightly nicer grammatically; it doesn't use "induction" as an adjective. But then the same argument applies to "induction step".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is acceptable, especially in technical English, to use nouns as adjectives. Indeed there are some cases where it is preferable: for example, *our China correspondent* refers to the correspondent based in China (who may not be Chinese). However, generally, keeping nouns and adjectives in their respective roles makes reading easier. This is particularly true in a many-word noun phrase. Since *inductive* is well established and understood, using it in this case costs nothing, and many people who care about such things would prefer it. (Incidentally, *noun phrase* is better than *substantive phrase* here, for ease of recognition in the present context.)